# sprocket(?) fail when using capybara selenium with middleman

Tags: selenium, capybara, sprockets, middleman

We've got a middleman site with some capybara acceptance tests running.  Everything works find outside of the test environment, but we're trying to use capybara with selenium so we can test a codemirror editor element via the send_keys method  https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/870

Our spec_helper.rb looks like this:

```
require 'middleman'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'

require 'middleman-core/load_paths'
Middleman.setup_load_paths

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.app = Middleman::Application.server.inst do
  set :root, File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))
  set :environment, :test
  set :show_exceptions, false
end
```

Selenium opens the firefox browser for us, however we get the following failure:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: makers_styles.
       Load paths:
         /Users/tansaku/Documents/Github/MakersAcademy/apply/source/stylesheets
         /Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
         Compass::SpriteImporter
        on line 5 of /Users/tansaku/Documents/Github/MakersAcademy/apply/source/stylesheets/site.css.scss

1: //= require _vendor/pygment_solarized_light
2: //= require _vendor/codemirror-solarized
3: //= require codemirror
4: 
5: @import "makers_styles";
6: 
7: .align-left {
8:   text-align: left;
9: }
10:
```

Using the network panel I can see this further backtrace:

```
Backtrace:
/Users/tansaku/Documents/Github/MakersAcademy/apply/source/stylesheets/site.css.scss:5
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:311:in `visit_import'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:17:in `block in render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:29:in `with_import_scope'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:16:in `render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/renderers/sass.rb:87:in `evaluate'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb:303:in `render_individual_file'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb:181:in `_render_with_all_renderers'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb:149:in `render_template'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/sitemap/resource.rb:127:in `block in render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/util.rb:41:in `instrument'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/application.rb:235:in `instrument'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/sitemap/resource.rb:14:in `instrument'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/sitemap/resource.rb:100:in `render'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:260:in `process_request'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:210:in `block in call!'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:209:in `catch'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:209:in `call!'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/middleman-core-3.3.12/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:195:in `call'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/tansaku/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any ideas? It all works fine in normal operation (we have makers_styles installed via bower, and all looks good outside of the test environment), but not in this capybara selenium setup ...

It seems like sprockets may not be adding the correct additional load paths in the testing setup ...

Comment: Where is the makers_style.scss (or _makers_style.scss) file located? Is it in one the listed load paths?

Comment: no, it's a folder in bower_components: i.e. "bower_components/makers_styles", and get's pulled in fine during normal operation